$G$ profinite group and $H$ closed subgroup of $G$ implies $G/H$ is totally disconnected
I'm reading the proof of the theorem that if $G$ is a profinite group and $H$ one of its closed subgroups then $G/H$ is totally disconnected in Ramakrishnan and Valenza's book. The authors put aside the case that $H$ is trivial. Now assume that $\rho$ is the canonical projection and $\rho(X)$ the connected component of identity in $G/H$ which properly contains $\rho(H)$. Since $H$ is non-trivial $Y=X-H$ is not a singleton and hence is a union of disjoint open sets $F_1$ and $F_2$. Now the authors conclude that since $H$ is closed in $X$ the sets $F_1$ and $F_2$ are clopen in $X$. I see that $H$ being closed in $X$ implies that $Y$ is open and an open set in an open subspace is open but I can't see how we can conclude that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are closed.

What are $Y_1$ and $Y_2$?

@KangyeonMoon Oh, I meant $F_1$ and $F_2$.

And you're absolutely right to ask that question.
There's not enough argument here to conclude that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are closed.
The book's authors interim assertion can be stated thus:

Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of a profinite group $G$ and $X\subset G$, $H\subset X$.  Let $Y=X-H$
and $Y=F_1\cup F_2$ where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are disjoint open sets in
$Y$.  Then $F_1$ and $F_2$ are closed in $X$.

This is wrong in general.
Here is a counterexample.
Let $F$ be an infinite profinite group and
$H=\langle a\rangle$ with $a^2=1$ be a finite group of order $2$.
Consider a profinite group $G=F\times H$.
Let
$$
X=G,\ F_1=F-1,\ F_2=aF-a,\ Y=X-H.
$$
We have
$$
Y=F_1\cup F_2,\ F_1\cap F_2=\varnothing,
$$
$F_1$ and $F_2$ are open sets in $Y$, and
$G=X=F_1\cup F_2\cup H$.
Clearly, $F_1$ and $F_2$ are not closed in $X=G$.
In spite of this, even a more general statement is true.

If
$G$ is a locally compact group and $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$
containing $G_0$ ($G_0$ is the identity connected component of $G$),
then $G/H$ is totally disconnected.

You can find the proof of this claim here (Claim 2) or here.
